# Body Template in Rundeck Email notification/Logout should not visible

Tags: rundeck

How to remove body of the content in rundeck job email notification and how to use customized output in job email notification

added below line to the file rundeck-config.properties and restarted rundeck
rundeck.execution.notification.bodyTemplate

In Rundeck UI , under Email notification selection , i can see subject section not body section.

im using rundeck version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom email notification (with a custom body or without body) you can use templates:

1. Stop the Rundeck service and locate the `rundeck-config.properties` file (usually at `/etc/rundeck` path if you have a Debian/Redhat based installation).
2. Add the following lines to configure the SMTP server (more info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/email-settings.html#smtp-server-settings)):

```
grails.mail.host=smtp_server_url
grails.mail.port=25
grails.mail.username=username
grails.mail.password=password
```

3. Then add the following lines to configure the template parameters (more info an customization settings [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/email-settings.html#custom-email-templates)):

```
rundeck.mail.template.subject=template
rundeck.mail.template.file=/path/to/your/template.html
rundeck.mail.template.log.formatted=true
```

On the `template.html` file you can use environments variables or anything that you want to see in the body, e.g:

```html
<h3>output: ${logoutput.data}</h3>
```

Or just "nothing" if you like.

4. Save the file and start the Rundeck instance.
5. Now, let's create a test job to see what happens when a job fails, so, create a new job with an invalid command. Also, go to "Notifications" tab and add an "On Failure" > "Send Email" (take a [look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP1Lx.jpg)), then save the job.
6. Run the job and check your SMTP inbox server.

A good place to test your email settings and templates is mailtrap.io, is a SMTP fake server.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

without adding SMTP server configuration , can we do it?

Is there any other method to do?

Comment: Only on Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") can you use the [configuration manager](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/configuration-mgmt/configmgmt.html#managing-configuration), but you must configure the SMTP server to send the email.